# Parse json output for a specific key in Ansible variable

Tags: json, ansible

I have a specific JSON output shown below using dummy data loaded inside a variable in Ansible:

```
 "nodes": {
            "100.29.28.153": {
                "agent": "UP",
                "db": "UP",
                "info": " ",
                "type": "Master",
                "xlog": "6C\\/2400A990",
                "xloginfo": ""
            },
            "100.29.28.154": {
                "agent": "UP",
                "db": "UP",
                "info": " ",
                "type": "Standby",
                "xlog": "6C\\/2400A990",
                "xloginfo": ""
            },
            "100.29.28.155": {
                "agent": "UP",
                "db": "N\\/A",
                "info": " ",
                "type": "Witness"
            },
            "100.29.28.163": {
                "agent": "UP",
                "db": "UP",
                "info": " ",
                "type": "Standby",
                "xlog": "6C\\/2400A990",
                "xloginfo": ""
            },
            "100.29.28.165": {
                "agent": "UP",
                "db": "N\\/A",
                "info": " ",
                "type": "Witness"
            }
        }
```

How do I parse this in Ansible and register a new variable using the type=Master as a means of selecting that nodes IP address? In the example above, the new Ansible variable should be set to **"100.29.28.153"** since that IP address is the Master node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example by combining `dict2items` filter with JMESPath:

```
- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ nodes | dict2items | json_query('[?value.type==`Master`] | [0].key') }}"
```